# Bass guitar solfeggietto adapted from guitar tab

Tags: guitar, tablature, electric-bass-guitar

I want to adapt the Solfeggietto by C.P.E. Bach, to play on my bass, [like seen here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nwnHQUMUXY).

First of all, I'm not a musician but a software developer. I've been playing bass for fun since I was a teenager and I've now decided to learn the notes on my fretboard.

I have found the Solfeggietto absolutely beautiful and would like to learn it on my bass, but I havent found a tab for the Solfeggietto [just for guitar](http://www.songsterr.com/a/wsa/at-vance-solfeggietto-tab-s1757t0) .

So how will I play the notes from the two strings from the guitar that are not on my 4 strings bass?

```
bass:   E A D G    

guitar: E A D G B E
```

I am just starting to learn about music theory [which is more complex than coding haha]

But what would be the equivalent of the B and E string on my strings?

Comment: It's "more complex than coding"... I took two years of calculus before I switched majors and took two years of music theory, and for me, music theory was more difficult than calculus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kmldfhrk0kllzkx/blah.png?dl=0) can help you.

But notice, that making a bass tab from guitar tab is like covering sb's cover of sb's cover :) It probably will work, but can be unplayable and inaccurate. The best adaptation would be the one you'd do from original music sheet.